# Finding number of steps with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I have the following reference table

```
+------+------+-----------+
| Min  | Max  | Step  size|
+------+------+-----------+
| 1.01 |    2 | 0.01      |
| 2.02 |    3 | 0.02      |
| 3.05 |    4 | 0.05      |
| 4.1  |    6 | 0.1       |
| 6.2  |   10 | 0.2       |
| 10.5 |   20 | 0.5       | 
| 21   |   30 | 1         |
| 32   |   50 | 2         |
| 55   |  100 | 5         |
| 110  | 1000 | 10        |
+------+------+-----------+
```

What I need is an Excel formula to find out how many steps there are between two given numbers from 1.01 to 1000.

For example

- from 1.01 to 1.02 there is 1 step
- from 2.02 to 2.06 there are 2 steps
- from 3.10 to 4.2 there are 20 steps (18 of 0.05 and 2 of 0.1)

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: How do you get from 6.2 to 10.5, using a step of 0.2?

Comment: @Dominique From 6.2 to 10.0 the step size is 0.2 from 10.0 to 10.5 the step is 0.5

Comment: Because there should be some effort to solve the problem as well as a problem statement (no, it wasn't me who downvoted it) - otherwise it's a reasonably interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, this would use the standard formula [described here for date ranges](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4280-excel-find-overlapping-date-ranges.html) to find the overlap between the two given numbers and the min and max values in each row of the table, then you just have to divide by the increments in the third column:

```
=SUM(TEXT(IF(B2:B11<F2,B2:B11,F2)-IF(A2:A11-C2:C11>E2,A2:A11-C2:C11,E2),"general;\0;\0")/C2:C11)
```

must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: An interesting solution. Only the link leads to your own screenshot.

Comment: Oops! Have fixed the link now.

Comment: This is a great solution however, it seems it is not working if, for instance, the start is bigger than the end. Es. Start=4.2 and End=3.1.

Comment: I have amended the formula with  the following: If(E2<F2,ArrayFormula(SUM(TEXT(IF(B2:B11<F2,B2:B11,F2)-IF(A2:A11-C2:C11>E2,A2:A11-C2:C11,E2),"general;\0;\0")/C2:C11)),ArrayFormula(SUM(TEXT(IF(B2:B11<E2,B2:B11,E2)-IF(A2:A11-C2:C11>F2,A2:A11-C2:C11,F2),"general;\0;\0")/C2:C11))*-1) and this seems working

Comment: Yes, I hadn't considered the case where the start is bigger than the end, but that should fix it (although it looks like a Google sheets implementation?)

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, it is a Google sheets implementation. I have decided to switch for practical reasons.